# Responsive design doesn't work on Iphones

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

First of all, this how chrome dev tools show it to me;

[image]

it looks normal and responsive, but I tried to send it to my friends and they sent me this;

[image]

As you can see, it's nothing like in my phone or chrome dev tools. Only in Iphones it looks like this. I have this code in index.html as well;

```
 <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />
```

I also made my friend download Chrome, but it's the same result.

Comment: You will need to update your question and include more of your code (HTML and CSS). Otherwise is impossible to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the devices, the size of certain things may vary. What Iphone does your friend have as well as yourself? This is important because Chrome uses those ratios and sizes to give a representation of how it will/should look. From the picture on your computer, you are testing on an Iphone 6,7 and 8 plus, but based on where the time, battery, etc. icons are on the phone screenshot, It looks as if your friend has an Iphone 10 or later.

You may use CSS `media queries` in order to have more control over how things are being displayed. *not an answer, just a suggestion*, but I hope this helps :)

Comment: Well I already used media queries a lot and it's fine everyone besides iphones.